# Can't reopen table. Temporary table used twice in select query

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Created a temporary table to store the subset I plan to retrieve more than once.

Here is my select query to select records from temporaryTable if the key with a different id exists in originalTable.

```
SELECT document 
FROM originalTable  
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM temporaryTable) AND key IN ( SELECT key FROM temporaryTable)
```

Any help?

I am coding in Java. Trying to avoid creating a permanent table.

Comment: What's the mean `Can't reopne table`?Is there any error?

Comment: can't reopen table is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `exists` to make your expect.

```
SELECT document 
FROM originalTable o
WHERE exists 
(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM temporaryTable t
   WHERE t.id <> o.id AND t.key = o.key
)
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks for the help